# How to get general relativity from linear gravity theory?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, approximations, linear-systems

I know someone had done this study. Namely the field approach to general relativity.

We can easily get an linear gravity theory. But it will be very complicated when we consider the self-interaction(The final result is we will get general relativity). How can we defeat this difficulties ?

Can you please show me some papers or articles about the mathematical details?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood you correct, but i think the end of Section 4.1. + the references in [Quantum Gravity: a Progress Report by S. Carlip](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0108040) seem relevant.

Comment: Maybe this [paper](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/S0218271808012085) by Padmanabhan, could interest you.

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32544/can-general-relativity-be-completely-described-as-a-field-in-a-flat-space#comment72143_32544