# can I simulate the curved space around a black hole with some kind of modified gravity

Tags: black-holes

After the publication of the so called image of a black hole (b.h:) I read something about the path of photons which come in the near of a b.h. I learned that there is a space of 2.6 Schwarzschild radii where no light can come form, and I understand this in principle.

I know that the space is curve and the path of the light is strait. Nevertheless. Is it possible to think the space as uncurved and simulate the deviation of the light by some kind of gravity? May it is necessary to modify the square-inverse formula by another one. It would be instructive if one could simulate the space around the b.h. with such an easy way.

Thank you for your help,

Uwe.

Answer (score 1):

Newtonian gravity has instantaneous action at a distance. This is incompatible with special relativity, so we can't make a viable alternative to general relativity by using instantaneous action at a distance and just modifying the $1/r^2$ form of the distance dependence.

What does work is to describe gravity as a dynamical field on a flat spacetime background. This is done in Deser, Gen Rel Grav 1 9(1970), http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0411023 . See also this question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32544/can-general-relativity-be-completely-described-as-a-field-in-a-flat-space

The result of this process is that after you get done adding an infinite series of corrections to the theory, you recover the equivalence principle, and the theory makes the same predictions as general relativity.