# Is it mathematically impossible to incorporate the space curvature into the equations of motion and gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, curvature, topology

Obviously, I haven't studied GR, I know no more than common knowledge. However, I'm wondering, is it impossible to develop a mathematical model based on flat space, in which the new equations of motion and gravity make the same predictions as GR? Or it's possible, but the equations will be very long and messy?

Comment: I think that this is a duplicate of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32544/), and that the answer, really, is 'yes, it is impossible' because the underlyng flat manifold is unobservable.  (I have therefore voted to close as duplicate.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can general relativity be completely described as a field in a flat space?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32544/)

Answer (score -1):

Newtonian physics is a special case of general relativity. It is described by the metric of flat space for special relativity where velocity is far less than the speed of light. In general, equations of motion in GR are described by the [geodesic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity), which involves Christoffel symbols. These symbols describe the curvature of spacetime.

Comment: I'm looking for a flat model with identical predictions in all cases, meaning exactness.