# Particle in "external potential" VS particle on "curved surface": equivalence?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, geodesics

Let's consider a non-relativistic particle - its position is $x(t)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ - in an external potential $\phi$, with Lagrangian $$L=\dot{x}^i \eta_{ij}\dot{x}^j/2 - \phi(x),\tag{1}$$
where  $\eta_{ij}$ is the flat spacetime metric tensor. How can we (if we can) map this problem into the one for a particle in a "curved" space with spatial metric $g_{ij}$? Namely,
$$
L \, \propto \, \dot{x}^i g_{ij}\dot{x}^j
$$
with $g = g(\phi)$. In other words, I'd like to understand if it's possible to perform the same "trick" of General relativity (i.e.: Newtonian potential ~ metric tensor) by using only "space": **how to obtain $g=g(\phi)$, if possible?**

More precisely:

We know the [Newtonian limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtonian_limit#:%7E:text=In%20physics%2C%20the%20Newtonian%20limit,or%20completely%20static)(small velocities and small curvature of spacetime) of General relativity: we recover the non-relativistic mechanics of a particle in a scalar potential $\phi$. *If* we are talking about gravity, then $\phi$ is the Newton potential defined in terms of the Poisson equation: I see no difficulties in applying the same construction for any generic (external) potential $\phi$ as well. However, *if* we follow the GR construction we have to encode the potential $\phi$ into the $g_{tt}$ part of the metric tensor. I am asking if it is possible do the same without invoking the spacetime structure and using $g_{ij}$, the metric of the "space manifold". **If this proves to be impossible, does it imply that the notion of space-time is a necessity in order to "geometrize" any kind of force?**

If this is possible, does it mean that it is always possible to map a problem of many particles in an external potential $\phi$ into the problem of particles that are constrained to move on a curved surface myth metric $g(\phi)$?

PS: [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/542434/226902) is very interesting and somewhat related, but mine is probably much simpler: I am not interested in the "dynamics" of $g$ since $\phi$ is just an external potential.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/105747/315444)?

Comment: @BillyIstiak, yes your link contains interesting considerations. I will go through it and in case add some comment to the question. Thank you!

Comment: Related: [How can we recover the Newtonian gravitational potential from the metric of general relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/211930/2451)

Comment: What did you mean by $g=g(\phi)$? Did you mean a spacetime metric is defined by $g$ and potential energy is function of that metric?

Comment: @BillyIstiak I mean that the spatial metric $g$ is the result of a mathematical procedure that has $\phi$ as input, e.g. a functional $g=g[\phi, \nabla \phi ]$. However, I am almost convinced that it is impossible to do so by using only space, it is necessary to introduce the notion of spacetime, i.e. to work in a setting where $i=0,1,2,3$ and $\dot x =(1,\dot x_1,\dot x_2,\dot x_3)$.

Comment: This paper contains many interesting insights for both classical particles and quantum mechanics: https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.23.1982 also this paper of Witt contains a deep discussion of systems on curved manifolds https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.29.377